# sed over ssh connection + unknown option to `s'

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

I have a sed command in a bash script like this:

```
sed -i 's/db.url=.*/db.url='$URL'/' config.properties
```

and URL var is assigned as:

```
$URL=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@\/\/hostname\:12345\/XYZ
```

When I run this bash script on the host it exists on it work as intended, replacing the url with the one specified in URL. However, when I add a command in the bash script to do this on my other host like this:

```
ssh user@host02 <<EOF
 sed -i 's/db.url=.*/db.url='$URL'/' config.properties
exit
EOF
```

I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: unknown option to `s'
```

Anyone know what may be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use double single quotes (') around $URL like this: ''$URL''

Answer (score 2):

You've properly quote the `sed` expression if it were running on the local host, but the string is then passed to the shell on the *remote* host, where the `*` is now unquoted and expanded as a glob. The simplest thing to do is to pipe the command to the remote shell via standard input, so you don't have to worry about quoting:

```
echo "sed -i 's/db.url=.*/db.url=$URL/' config.properties" | ssh user@host02 bash
```

With multiple commands, you may consider using a here document:

```
ssh user@host02 bash <<EOF
command1
sed -i 's/db.url=.*/db.url=$URL/' config.properities
command2
EOF
```

Comment: Could I just quote the command inside the ssh? I have many commands being called besides this one and obviously don't want to pipe every one, I also don't want to make this a standalone command.

Comment: You may also want to consider simply `scp`ing a locally written script and executing that remotely via `ssh`. Trying to get the quoting right will be tricky at best, impossible at worst. A here document may also be useful.

Comment: I already do use a here doc, as indicated in my original example

Comment: also, I do scp the file over to the other host, I use ssh to run the bash script where it gets moved to.

Comment: The difference is, I am explicitly running a `bash` instance on the remote end.

Comment: I added the bash to the command and it's still giving same error